# tags with FPNTagBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.8

I have this problem when I use FPNTagBundle for system tags:

this problem dispaly when I refresh a page web

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tag (name, slug, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "", "2017-06-28 17:41:34", "2017-06-28 17:41:34"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
500 Internal Server Error - NotNullConstraintViolationException
2 linked Exceptions: PDOException » PDOException »

code controller:

```
  public function createTagsAction()
{
    // create your entity
     $post = new Post();
    $post->setTitle('salah');

    $tagManager = $this->get('fpn_tag.tag_manager');
        $f = $this->container->get('request')->request->get('data');

    // ask the tag manager to create a Tag object
    $fooTag = $tagManager->loadOrCreateTag($f);

    // assign the foo tag to the post
    $tagManager->addTag($fooTag, $post);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    // persist and flush the new post
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();

    // after flushing the post, tell the tag manager to actually save the tags
    $tagManager->saveTagging($post);

    // ...

    // Load tagging ...
    $tagManager->loadTagging($post);

    $m = "success";

    return $this->render('MedBundle:Default:tag.html.twig',array('m' => $m));
}
```

code twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>tags</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/med/css/jquery.tagit.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h3>
{{ m }}
</h3>
<input type="text" id="myTags" placeholder="your tags" >

<br><br> <input type="submit" id="add" value="add article" >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/med/js/tag-it.js') }}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit();
    });

});

 $( "#add" ).click(function() {
    $ch = $.trim( $("#myTags").val() );
    var $leng = $ch.length;
    console.log($leng);
    $j = 0;


    var $_data = $ch;

      $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "{{path('tag')}}",
            data: $_data,
            success: function(data) {

               console.log("valide");
            },


        });

        });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Entities:

Post.php

```
<?php

    namespace test\MedBundle\Entity;


    use DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Taggable;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="acme_post")
     */
    class Post implements Taggable
    {

        /**
         * @var integer $id
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        private $tags;

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $title;


         /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }


         /**
         * Set title
         *
         * @param string $title
         * @return Post
         */
        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get title
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }



        public function getTags()
        {
            $this->tags = $this->tags ?: new ArrayCollection();

            return $this->tags;
        }

        public function getTaggableType()
        {
            return 'acme_tag';
        }

        public function getTaggableId()
        {
            return $this->getId();
        }
    }
```

Tagging.php:

```
<?php

    namespace test\MedBundle\Entity;

    use \FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging as BaseTagging;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;

    /**
     * test\MedBundle\Entity
     *
     * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="tagging_idx", columns={"tag_id", "resource_type", "resource_id"})})
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Tagging extends BaseTagging
    {
        /**
         * @var integer $id
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         **/
        protected $tag;
    }
```

Tag.php:

```
<?php

    namespace test\MedBundle\Entity;

    use \FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tag as BaseTag;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * test\MedBundle\Entity
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Tag extends BaseTag
    {
        /**
         * @var integer $id
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tagging", mappedBy="tag", fetch="EAGER")
         **/
        protected $tagging;
    }
```

help me please for resolve this problem and thanks

Comment: please share your entity

Comment: I edited subject when I add entities

Comment: help me please ...